# how to save songs from spotify on pc

Tags: spotify

it's first time I'm using spotify and I installed spotify for linux on my ubuntu.
I can listen to musics but I don't know how to download them on my PC or does it save songs on pc in a feature folder?
please help me.

Answer (score 7):

you cant get the mp3 song from spotify, however you can use the information that provide spotify in order to download it in other place (information like name of the song, length and so on), this little app offers that: 
https://github.com/frosas/spotify-to-mp3
the instalation setup and usage is written in there, its very easy to use.

If you have problems installing this app, probably is because you are using an old version of ruby (by default is 1.8.7), you need to upgrade it to 1.9.2 and then install the app.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Isn't it illegal to download from Spotify?

Comment: you are not downloading the song directly from spotify as i mentioned, you are only using the song information to download it in other place (legal or illegal, that's up to you) in this case this app is fetching the info and search that on Grooveshark (which is music streaming service), so i guess you get the point.

Comment: Any possible way to copy all URI from a playlist at once?

Comment: the gem doesnt parse the entire playlist URI, so you need to grab the song URI one by one, however you can grab all the songs inside playlist with ctrl and then right click them to copy all the URIs at once.

Comment: @PedroDusso See: [How to download an album?](https://github.com/frosas/spotify-to-mp3/issues/19)

Comment: Isn't Groveshrk closed?

Comment: This particular service doesn't work anymore, and the answer is outdated.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a premium account you can sync playlists to be available offline, however you will never have access to the raw MP3 files (actually Spotify serves OGG vorbis files though that's beside the point).

The service is for streaming music only, but why would you want to store the files on your drive anyways? They'll always be waiting for you online, that's the entire point of Spotify! :)

Comment: I prefer to have them on my drive I can use them on mobile and etc ... . and the most big problem is that internet is expensive in my country!

Comment: Then offline sync is probably the way to go. The mobile client also supports offline sync, just so you know.

Comment: @NikReiman `> They'll always be waiting for you online` The problem with the internet: **everything is temporary**, including Spotify. Not even NewGrounds can hold a candle to this. In at least 10 years, all of your favorite media will disappear.